# What values do arrow keys return with getch()?

Tags: c, arrow-keys

I read that you have to use getch() twice to get a value when an arrow key is pressed. The first call returns 0 for arrow keys and the second call returns another value (eg. 77 for right arrow keys). I wrote the following program to confirm this, but the first value I get is 224, not zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
    int main()  
    {  
        printf("Start: (x to quit)\n");  
        int d = getch();  
        int e = getch();  
        printf("%d", d);  
        printf("\n%d", e);  
    }
```

Why is the first value not zero, and what is the significance of 224?

Comment: `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: There are at least two quite different functions called `getch`. One is specific to Windows, and is (I think) declared in `<conio.h>`. Another is part of the Unix "curses" library. You're probably using the Windows version. If so, please update your question with a "windows" tag to make that clear.

Comment: None of the given answers improve on any of the possible duplicates for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "escape" code `0` applies to the numeric keypad (with `NumLock` off). The dedicated cursor control keys (and `Home` etc) use the escape code `224`. Please try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int d=-1, e=-1;
    printf("Start:\n");  
    d = _getch();  
    if (d == 0 || d == 224)
       e = _getch();  
    printf("%d %d\n", d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

Note too that the MSVC function `getch()` is deprecated, use `_getch()` (these are non-echoing versions of `getche()` and `_getche()`).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    printf("Start: (x to quit)\n");  
    char d = _getche();  
    char e = _getche();  
    printf("%c", d);  
    printf("\n%c", e);  
}
```

I didn't try it but i think it will work