# how to use mov ah, 0 int 16h so that the snake moves continuously

Tags: assembly, buffer, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I'm making the snake game and ran into a problem.
For now, I used `int 21h`, so it only moved when I pressed a key. Now I want it to move continuously so it isn't waiting for me to press a key but just checks if there's something in the buffer. To do that I'm using `ah 0h and int 16h` however, I don't know how to do that it'll always move. I think I need to add a loop somewhere that checks what is in `dir` and based on that it goes to where it's supposed to go but I just don't know what the loop is supposed to look like (I also think I should use delay if I'm not wrong).
I think the relevant parts are:

```
    mov ah, 0h
    int 16h
    mov [byte ptr saveal], al
    
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'w'
    jz w
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'a'
    jz a
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 's'
    jz s
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'd'
    jz d
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'q'
    jmp exit
    
w:
    mov [byte ptr dir], 1
    call up
    jmp wasd
s:
    mov [byte ptr dir], 2
    call down
    jmp wasd    
a:
    mov [byte ptr di], 3
    call left
    jmp wasd
d:
    mov [byte ptr dir], 4
    call right
    jmp wasd
```

The whole code is:

```
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------
saveal db ' '
dir db 0       ;not used

app dw 0       ;place of the apple
st_am dw 3
stars dw 0, 0, 0  ;places of the *

CODESEG
proc black
body:
    mov [es:si], ax
    add si, 2
    cmp si, 25*80*2
    jnz body
  ret
endp black

proc up
    mov di, 80*2
    cmp si, di
    jb not_move_up
    
    cmp si, [app]
    jnz move_up
    call apple
    
move_up:
    call delete
    call replace_stars

    sub si, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
not_move_up:
  ret
endp up
proc down

    mov di, (24*80*2)-1
    cmp si, di
    jg not_move_down
    
    cmp si, [app]
    jnz move_down
    call apple
    
move_down:
    call delete
    call replace_stars
    
    add si, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
not_move_down:
  ret
endp down
proc left

    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, si
    mov ax, si
    mov si, 80*2
    div si
    mov si, bx
    cmp dx,0
    jz not_move_left
    
    cmp si, [app]
    jnz move_left
    call apple
    
move_left:
    call delete
    call replace_stars
    
    sub si, 2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
not_move_left:
  ret
endp left
proc right

    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, si
    mov ax, si
    mov si, 80*2
    div si
    mov si, bx
    cmp dx,158
    jz not_move_right
    
    cmp si, [app]
    jnz move_right
    call apple
    
move_right:
    call delete
    call replace_stars
    
    add si, 2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
not_move_right:
  ret
endp right

proc apple
    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, [es:6ch]
    and ax, 0000001111111110b
    mov di,ax
    mov [app], di
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov al, '@'
    mov ah, 154
    mov [es:di], ax
  ret 
endp apple
    
proc delete
    mov bx, offset stars
    mov di, [st_am]
    dec di
    shl di, 1
    mov di, [bx+di]
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov al, ' '
    mov ah, 0
    
    mov [es:di], ax
  ret
endp delete

proc replace_stars
    mov  bx, [st_am]   ; The amount of stars (3 or more)
    dec  bx
    shl  bx, 1         ; Offset to the last star
replace:
    mov  ax, [stars+bx-2]
    mov  [stars+bx], ax
    sub  bx, 2
    jnz  replace
  ret
endp replace_stars

proc first_3_dots
    mov bx, offset stars
    mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)-2
    mov al, '*'
    mov ah, 156
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [bx], si
    mov si, (12*80+40)*2
    mov al, '*'
    mov ah, 156
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [bx+2], si
    mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)+2
    mov al, '*'
    mov ah, 156
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [bx+4], si
  ret
endp first_3_dots

proc delay
    mov cx, 0FFFFh
delay1:
    mov ax, 300
delay2:
    dec ax
    jnz delay2
    loop delay1
  ret
endp delay

proc incS
    
  ret
endp incS

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
; Your code here
; --------------------------
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov si,0
    mov al, ' '
    mov ah, 0
    call black
    
    call first_3_dots
    mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)-2    

    call apple
    
wasd:
    mov ah, 0h
    int 16h
    mov [byte ptr saveal], al
    
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'w'
    jz w
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'a'
    jz a
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 's'
    jz s
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'd'
    jz d
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'q'
    jmp exit
    
w:
    mov [byte ptr dir], 1
    call up
    jmp wasd
s:
    mov [byte ptr dir], 2
    call down
    jmp wasd    
a:
    mov [byte ptr di], 3
    call left
    jmp wasd
d:
    mov [byte ptr dir], 4
    call right
    jmp wasd
    
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I need to add a loop somewhere that checks what is in dir and based on that it goes to where it's supposed to go but I just don't know what the loop is supposed to look like

You don't need an additional loop. The *wasd* main loop is fine. But instead of waiting (blocking) for the user to press a key, simply check (non-blocking) if the user has already pressed a key. If a key is indeed available then **store its info in the *dir* variable** and use it normally. And if no key is available right now, then use whatever is in the *dir* variable **as if it had been pressed right now**.

Instead of using values {1,2,3,4}, I would use the ASCII codes themselves, so {'w','a','s','d'}.
Seeing how you have initialized the snake, I also suggest you initialize the *dir* variable to point to the left (`dir db 'a'`).

```
wasd:
  mov  ah, 01h   ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
  int  16h       ; -> AX ZF
  mov  al, [dir]
  jz   .key      ; No key available, continue in the same direction
  mov  ah, 00h   ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
  int  16h       ; -> AX
.key:
  mov  [saveal], al
  cmp  al, 'w'
  je   .w
  cmp  al, 'a'
  je   .a
  cmp  al, 's'
  je   .s
  cmp  al, 'd'
  je   .d
  cmp  al, 'q'
  je   exit
  jmp  wasd      ; Invalid key
    
.w:
  mov  [dir], al
  call up
  jmp  wasd
.s:
  mov  [dir], al
  call down
  jmp  wasd    
.a:
  mov  [dir], al ; You had a typo in `mov [byte ptr di], 3` !!!
  call left      ;                                    ^ 
  jmp  wasd
.d:
  mov  [dir], al
  call right
  jmp  wasd

exit:
  mov  ax, 4C00h
  int  21h
```

> (I also think I should use delay if I'm not wrong).

Correct. With the above changes everything will become much too fast. You need to add a suitable delay to the main loop. Waiting for one tick on the BIOS timer is already a good solution:

```
wasd:
  xor  ax, ax               ; Equivalent to `mov ax, 0`
  mov  ds, ax               ; This sets DS=0
  mov  ax, [word ptr 046Ch] ; Reads the BIOS timer at address DS:046Ch

.wait:                      ; For as long as the timer hasn't changed,
  cmp  ax, [word ptr 046Ch] ; we stay in this tight loop
  je   .wait                ; Should never take longer than 1/18 sec

  mov  ax, @data            ; This restores DS to what you have set
  mov  ds, ax               ; at program start

  mov  ah, 01h     ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
  int  16h         ; -> AX ZF
  mov  al, [dir]
  jz   .key        ; No key available, continue the same direction

  ...
```

If it still doesn't work, then try next code that is similar to your very own *apple* procedure:

```
wasd:
  mov  ax, 0040h
  mov  es, ax
  mov  ax, [es:6Ch]
.wait:
  cmp  ax, [es:6Ch]
  je   .wait
  mov  ax, 0B800h
  mov  es, ax

  mov  ah, 01h     ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
  int  16h         ; -> AX ZF
  mov  al, [dir]
  jz   .key        ; No key available, continue the same direction

  ...
```

And in case TASM is a really stupid assembler, then also change:

```
mov al, [dir]      -->    mov al, [byte ptr dir]
mov [saveal], al   -->    mov [byte ptr saveal], al
mov [dir], al      -->    mov [byte ptr dir], al
mov [dir], al      -->    mov [byte ptr dir], al
mov [dir], al      -->    mov [byte ptr dir], al
mov [dir], al      -->    mov [byte ptr dir], al
```

[**EDIT**]

> I assume what you wanted me to is: ```wasd: xor ax, ax mov ds, ax mov ax, [word ptr 046Ch] waitt: ;cant do .wait cmp ax, [word ptr 046Ch] ; je waitt mov ax, @data mov ds, ax mov ah, 0h int 16h mov al, [dir] jz key mov ah, 0h int 16h key: mov [byte ptr saveal], al cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'q' jz exit... ```` it's still takes a long time to respond to a pressed key.

Your recent comment contains a typo that could explain why it still takes a long time to respond. The first time that you wrote `mov ah, 0h` `int 16h`, it needs to be `mov ah, 01h` `int 16h`.

As I was curious whether it would actually work, I have translated your complete program for [the FASM assembler](https://flatassembler.net). I believe FASM is superior to TASM, so if you're not forced to use TASM, you could consider becoming a FASM user. FASM is a modern assembler that is being actively maintainded by its author, supported by a community, and that comes with an easy to use IDE with no need for any external linker.

I'm happy to report that it all works! One change that I needed to make though, is slowing the program down even more, by turning the simple delay loop into a pair of nested loops that wait for about 3/18 sec. For your convenience, I have refrained from most other changes...

```
  ORG  256         ; For a program with the .COM extension

; *** SETUP ***
  mov  ax, 0B800h  ; CONST ES = 0B800h
  mov  es, ax
  mov  si, 0
  mov  al, ' '
  mov  ah, 0
  call black
  call first_3_dots
  mov  si, ((12*80+40)*2)-2
  call apple

; *** MAIN LOOP ***
wasd:
  push ds          ; (1)
  xor  ax, ax      ; Equivalent to `mov ax, 0`
  mov  ds, ax      ; This sets DS=0
  mov  cx, 3       ; Wait about 3/18 sec
.w1:
  mov  ax, [046Ch] ; Reads the BIOS timer at address DS:046Ch
.w2:               ; For as long as the timer hasn't changed,
  cmp  ax, [046Ch] ; we stay in this tight loop
  je   .w2         ; Should never take longer than 1/18 sec
  loop .w1
  pop  ds          ; (1) This restores DS

  mov  ah, 01h     ; BIOS.CheckKeystroke
  int  16h         ; -> AX ZF
  mov  al, [dir]
  jz   .key        ; No key available, continue the same direction
  mov  ah, 00h     ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
  int  16h         ; -> AX
.key:
  mov  [saveal], al
  cmp  al, 'w'
  je   .w
  cmp  al, 'a'
  je   .a
  cmp  al, 's'
  je   .s
  cmp  al, 'd'
  je   .d
  cmp  al, 'q'
  je   exit
  jmp  wasd      ; Invalid key
    
.w:
  mov  [dir], al
  call up
  jmp  wasd
.s:
  mov  [dir], al
  call down
  jmp  wasd    
.a:
  mov  [dir], al
  call left
  jmp  wasd
.d:
  mov  [dir], al
  call right
  jmp  wasd

exit:
  mov  ax, 4C00h
  int  21h

; *** PROCEDURES ***
black:
  mov  [es:si], ax
  add  si, 2
  cmp  si, 25*80*2
  jnz  black
  ret

up:
  mov  di, 80*2
  cmp  si, di
  jb   not_move_up
  cmp  si, [app]
  jnz  move_up
  call apple
move_up:
  call delete
  call replace_stars
  sub  si, 80*2
  mov  ah, 156
  mov  al, '*'
  mov  [es:si], ax
  mov  [stars], si
not_move_up:
  ret

down:
  mov  di, (24*80*2)-1
  cmp  si, di
  jg   not_move_down
  cmp  si, [app]
  jnz  move_down
  call apple
move_down:
  call delete
  call replace_stars
  add  si, 80*2
  mov  ah, 156
  mov  al, '*'
  mov  [es:si], ax
  mov  [stars], si
not_move_down:
  ret

left:
  mov  dx, 0
  mov  bx, si
  mov  ax, si
  mov  si, 80*2
  div  si
  mov  si, bx
  cmp  dx, 0
  jz   not_move_left
  cmp  si, [app]
  jnz  move_left
  call apple
move_left:
  call delete
  call replace_stars
  sub  si, 2
  mov  ah, 156
  mov  al, '*'
  mov  [es:si], ax
  mov  [stars], si
not_move_left:
  ret

right:
  mov  dx, 0
  mov  bx, si
  mov  ax, si
  mov  si, 80*2
  div  si
  mov  si, bx
  cmp  dx, 158
  jz   not_move_right
  cmp  si, [app]
  jnz  move_right
  call apple
move_right:
  call delete
  call replace_stars
  add  si, 2
  mov  ah, 156
  mov  al, '*'
  mov  [es:si], ax
  mov  [stars], si
not_move_right:
  ret

apple:
  mov  ax, 40h
  mov  es, ax
  mov  ax, [es:6ch]
  and  ax, 0000001111111110b
  mov  di, ax
  mov  [app], di
  mov  ax, 0b800h
  mov  es, ax
  mov  al, '@'
  mov  ah, 154
  mov  [es:di], ax
  ret 
        
delete:
  mov  bx, stars
  mov  di, [st_am]
  dec  di
  shl  di, 1
  mov  di, [bx+di]
  mov  ax, 0b800h
  mov  es, ax
  mov  al, ' '
  mov  ah, 0
  mov  [es:di], ax
  ret

replace_stars:
  mov  bx, [st_am]   ; The amount of stars (3 or more)
  dec  bx
  shl  bx, 1         ; Offset to the last star
replace:
  mov  ax, [stars+bx-2]
  mov  [stars+bx], ax
  sub  bx, 2
  jnz  replace
  ret

first_3_dots:
  mov bx, stars
  mov al, '*'
  mov ah, 156
  mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)-2
  mov [es:si], ax
  mov [bx], si
  mov si, (12*80+40)*2
  mov [es:si], ax
  mov [bx+2], si
  mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)+2
  mov [es:si], ax
  mov [bx+4], si
  ret
; ------------------------------
saveal db 0
dir    db 0

app    dw 0        ; place of the apple
st_am  dw 3
stars  dw 0, 0, 0  ; places of the *
```

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to decode the ASCII character from the keyboard to an integer with some internal meaning that might require less decoding later.  Like -1 / +1 for left/right, and -80 / +80 for up/down if you're on an 80-column screen.  Although that's not super helpful if you have separate X and Y variables, not just framebuffer offsets.  Still, hard-coding the key bindings into the rest of your code that's going to use `dir` seems like a terrible idea, making it harder to change to numpad or arrow keys (unless you do it by mapping those to ASCII wasd instead of storing the scancode)

Comment: Instead of push/pop AX around the first BIOS call, you could just `mov  al, [dir]` after it, but before the `jz`, since `mov` doesn't affect FLAGS.

Comment: @PeterCordes Decoding the character code into some meaningful new value would make sense if they wanted to go *much further* with this snake project. But from what I have learned from the OP that is not the case. So not worth translating to an arbitrary number. Nice catch on that `push ax` `pop ax`. Again something the OP doesn't like because they haven't learned it yet!

Comment: I tried to run it:
1) When I pressed a key it took a long time to react
2) It didn't move continually.
I also didn't understand the second part.

Comment: @yarden I see nothing in your code from the question nor in my replacement for the *wasd* part, that can trigger a 'long time to react'. Likely you have made additional changes and/or not fully copy/pasted my new codez. I will add some more comments to the waiting loop.

Comment: @yarden Maybe TASM interpreted `mov ax, [046Ch]` not the way I intended it. I have modified my answer to read `mov ax, [word ptr 046Ch]`. I hope that is acceptable syntax for TASM to generate a memory reference... I have also added another code snippet as a last resort.

Comment: I assume what you wanted me to is:
```wasd:
    xor  ax, ax
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  ax, [word ptr 046Ch]

waitt:       ;cant do .wait
  cmp  ax, [word ptr 046Ch] ; 
  je waitt 

mov  ax, @data
mov  ds, ax
mov ah, 0h
int 16h
mov  al, [dir]
jz key
mov  ah, 0h
int  16h
 
key:
mov [byte ptr saveal], al
 
cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'q'
    jz exit...
````
it's still takes a long time to respond to a pressed key.

Comment: @yarden: Check out Sep's edit.  The edit changelog message says he was unable to post comments because of a possible browser problem, so he couldn't reply himself to let you know about the edit.

Comment: IT WORKED !! Thank you so much! However, could you explain what the data segment (ds) had to do with this? Also, is there a way to control how fast it moves? About the FASM & TASM, I am obligated to use TASM but maybe in the future I'll consider using FASM

Comment: @yarden In your TASM program you set the DS segment register to point at the DATASEG section (`mov ax, @data` `mov ds, ax`). That is fine of course, but **using DS must not be restricted to only the DATASEG**. In my code that waits a certain amount of time, I have temporarily used the DS segment register for another purpose, and I have preferred using DS over ES because with DS you don't have to write a segment override prefix  (like you were doing in your *apple* proc `[es:6ch]). Every segment override prefix that you avoid shaves off a byte from the encoded program.

Comment: @yarden If you want to dynamically control the speed of the snake, then you should replace the hardcoded number 3 in `mov cx, 3` by a reference to a memory-based variable (`mov cx, [SpeedOfSnake]`) and a matching definition in the DATASEG (`SpeedOfSnake dw 3`).  In the main loop of the program you would add detection of presses of the + or - keys, and increment or decrement the *SpeedOfSnake* variable accordingly. If you prefer so, you can opt for any other keys that you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Int 16h with function 01h (non-blocking) to check if a key has been pressed, and if so, function 00h to read the key.

These are probably used by MSVC's `_kbhit()` and `_getch()`, where some key presses will provide more than one character: if the first is an 'escape' value such as 0 or 224 for function and cursor control keys, then another value is immediately available. This is shown in a [C code answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34256166/4142924)

That may be the way those BIOS functions work too. You don't seem to use cursor control keys, but maybe you can now!

Comment: It is DOS that works the way you describe (sending the 'escape' value 0 and expecting the user to come back for the true key code. BIOS on the other hand delivers the complete information first time: ASCII code in the AL register and scancode in AH.